# Linux Shell script Sed inserting

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I need to write a shell script to insert a parameter string after every big letter in a file.

```
$parameter="4"
```

Example `input.txt`

```
AppLe
House
```

Example `output.txt`

```
A4ppL4e
H4ouse
```

I've tried to use

```
sed '/[A-Z]/i\$1\'
```

Can anyone help me?
THX

Comment: Welcome to S.O., so what have you tried?

Comment: i tried something like this: sed '/[A-Z]/i\$1\'

Comment: Please add sample input (no descriptions, no images, no links) and your desired output for that sample input to your question (no comment)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With GNU/BSD/busybox `sed` which support the `-i` option:

```
param=4
sed -i'' -e 's/\([[:upper:]]\)/\1'"$param"'/g' input.txt
```

This replaces each uppercase letter inside the captured group `\(...\)` `g`lobally with the first captured group `\1` and the value of variable `param` in-place.

---

With standard `sed` you need a temporary file or `sponge` from the `moreutils` package:

```
param=4
sed 's/\([[:upper:]]\)/\1'"$param"'/g' input.txt > temp && mv temp input.txt

param=4
sed 's/\([[:upper:]]\)/\1'"$param"'/g' input.txt | sponge input.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a file editor like `ed` to edit files:

```
printf "%s\n" 'g/[[:upper:]]/s/\([[:upper:]]\)/\1'"$param"'/g' w | ed -s input.txt
```

or if you like heredocs better

```
ed -s input.txt <<EOF
g/[[:upper:]]/s/\([[:upper:]]\)/\1${param}/g
w
EOF
```